# google app engine yaml index.html

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want a get request for any url ending in "/" like http://website.com/some_dir/ to receive the index.html file inside that directory... in my example it should receive http://website.com/some_dir/index.html  .

i have it working locally with the GAE Launcher/local-server... but when I deploy it and access it via website.appspot.com it fails...
i get the error:

> Error: Not Found
>
> The requested URL /some_dir/ was not found on this server.

this is what i have in my yaml:

```
- url: /
  static_files: staticLocation/index.html
  upload: staticLocation/index.html
- url: (.+)/
  static_files: staticLocation/\1/index.html
  upload: staticLocation
- url: /
  static_dir: staticLocation
```

I'm curious as to how/why it works great locally, but not on appspot...
ideas, and how to fix my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your 'upload' line for the 2nd route isn't detailed enough, so the files inside won't be deployed to appengine. You want something like:

```
- url: (.+)/
  static_files: staticLocation/\1/index.html
  upload: staticLocation/(.*)

- url: /(.+)
  static_files: staticLocation/\1/index.html
  upload: staticLocation/(.+)/index.html
```

(Your last route has the same url as the first, so it's never going to be hit and could be removed.)

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed your issue. Works locally but not on appspot. To fix your problem change:

```
- url: (.+)/
  static_files: staticLocation/\1/index.html
```

to

```
- url: (.*)/
  static_files: staticLocation\1/index.html`
```

and it should work properly. (note: `+` was changed to `*` in `url` and a `/` was removed in `static_files`)

To satisfy your curiosity you were matching the leading `/` so the file system location lookup was `staticlocation//some_dir/index.html` which works fine on your filesystem because `//` collapses down to just `/` in your OS. I presume that appspot's path lookup does not collapse the `//` which results in not locating your index.html file.

Oh and by the way, fixing the second rule like I mentioned will make it so you don't need the first rule at all so that rule can be removed.

Answer (score -1):

AppEngine production servers are case sensitive file system, check that both casing matches.